# Calling (overloaded) RxJava functions from Scala

Tags: scala, rx-java, rx-scala

I wanted to create an `Observable` from an array of `Observable`s like this:

```
package rxtest

import concurrent._
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import rx.lang.scala._
import rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions._
import rx.lang.scala.schedulers._

object A extends App {
    val ps = Array.fill(3)(Promise[Int]())
    val os = ps map {
            p => Observable from p.future observeOn NewThreadScheduler()
        }
    val v = rx.Observable.merge(os map toJavaObservable)
}
```

This program does not compile since [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html) has several overloaded methods all called `merge`:

```
[error] /home/xgp/work/rxtest/src/main/scala/rxtest/A.scala:15: overloaded method value merge with alternatives:
[error]   [T](x$1: Array[rx.Observable[_ <: T]])rx.Observable[T] <and>
[error]   [T](x$1: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[_ <: T]])rx.Observable[T] <and>
[error]   [T](x$1: Iterable[_ <: rx.Observable[_ <: T]])rx.Observable[T]
[error]  cannot be applied to (Array[rx.Observable[_ <: Int]])
[error]     val v = rx.Observable.merge(os map toJavaObservable)
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
```

Then I wanted to remove the overloading with the help of another Java class:

```
public class RxUtils {
    public final static <T> Observable<T> merge(Observable<? extends T>[] os) {
        return Observable.merge(os);
    }
}
```

The Scala code became (only the relevant part is listed here):

```
val ps = Array.fill(3)(Promise[Int]())
val os = ps map {
        p => Observable from p.future observeOn NewThreadScheduler()
    }
val v = RxUtils.merge(os map toJavaObservable)
```

This program still does not compile:

```
[error] /home/xgp/work/rxtest/src/main/scala/rxtest/A.scala:17: no type parameters for method merge: (os: Array[rx.Observable[_ <: T]])rx.Observable[T] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Array[rx.Observable[_ <: Int]])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : Array[rx.Observable[_ <: Int]]
[error]  required: Array[rx.Observable[_ <: ?T]]
[error]     val v = RxUtils.merge(os map toJavaObservable)
[error]                     ^
[error] /home/xgp/work/rxtest/src/main/scala/rxtest/A.scala:17: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[rx.Observable[_ <: Int]]
[error]  required: Array[rx.Observable[_ <: T]]
[error]     val v = RxUtils.merge(os map toJavaObservable)
[error]                              ^
[error] two errors found
```

I have three questions:

1. How to call the `merge` method with pure Scala like in the first case?
2. Why does the second program not compile?
3. How to call the `merge` method in the above `RxUtils` class in Scala?

Comment: If you are really interested in black magic of Java and Scala generic, check how RxScala implements `flatten`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/a385e1a474a05af5173d3a6c5f380b0f87b50dff/src/main/scala/rx/lang/scala/Observable.scala#L2669

Answer (score 2):

I'm really confused with what you're doing here. Why do you mix `rx.Observable` and `rx.lang.scala.Observable`. Just choose either one of them: if you're working in Scala, choose the latter; if you're writing Java code, choose the former!

I also want to point you to [this page](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/comparison.html), which compares both kinds of `Observable`.

Regarding your first program, if I'm correct the type of `ps` is `Array[Promise[Int]]`, so `os` must have the type `Array[Observable[Int]]`. If you want to merge all of them into one single `Observable`, you can follow the link above and search for `merge(Array<Observable<? extends T>>)` in the left column. Turns out, you can write this in Scala as `Observable.from(os).flatten` or `os.toObservable.flatten`.

Regarding the second and third question: I haven't really checked this, but it probably has to do with covariance differences between Java and Scala. Probably helping the type system with providing some extra type information will do the trick. But I guess, if you just stay in the Scala language and use the RxScala library as it is meant to be, you will not have to deal with problems like this at all.